# Is $[a,b]$ a finite or an infinite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$.

> Question: Is $[a,b]$ a finite set or not?

The question popped up in my mind while I was working with the Extreme Value Theorem of continuous functions. Clearly, the set has a lower bound and an upper bound, but the set itself can have infinite elements, as you can always find a real number between any two real numbers.

The question can be stated in another way too: Is a set finite if it has finite number of elements, or is a set finite if it has well defined upper and lower bounds?

Comment: Infinite and bounded.

Comment: "Is a set finite if it has finite number of elements" Yes. "is a set finite if it has well defined upper and lower bounds?" No.

Comment: (you mean "infinitely many elements" or "an infinite number of elements"; saying "$[a,b]$ has infinite elements" is like saying "$\{1,7\}$ has even elements". If you want a name for the number of elements, it's $2^{\aleph_0}$; sometimes $\mathfrak{c}$ is used as well, or $|\mathbb{R}|$)

Comment: I think you are confusing "finite" with "bounded"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A set is finite (per definition) if it contains only finitely many elements.
The interval (more like: the set) $[a,b]$ is infinite because it contains infinitely many elements and it is bounded because it has both lower and upper bounds.

Answer (score 3):

According to set theory (and in particular to the theory of cardinalities), a set $A$ is infinite if there exists a bijection between $A$ and a proper subset of $A$. For any closed interval $[a,b]$ it is very easy to establish this. For any $\varepsilon \in (a,b)$ where $2\varepsilon < b$, we can take

$$f(x) = (x-a) \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{b-a} + \varepsilon$$

This $f$ (whose graph is easily seen to be a line segment) is a bijection between $[a,b]$ and $[\varepsilon,2\varepsilon]$.

Answer (score 2):

It's infinite, but what are you thinking is about of the measure of the interval, the measure of the interval is finite but the interval itself as a set not.

Answer (score 1):

In short, we know that $(0,1)$ is infinite set, thus $(a,b)$ is infinite.

Let's look at $[a,b]$. We see that $(a,b)$ is a subset of $[a,b]$, thus $[a,b]$ is infinite.